# Django REST Framework: Strange behaviour in unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, permissions

Good evening,

at the moment I'm creating the unit tests for a pretty basic model in combination with the authentification of a *json web token*. Also I'm using a custom user model. Notice: a few lines of code will be cut off for a better overview - there unimportant for my question.

**models.py:**

```
USER = get_user_model()

class MainTask(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(USER, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
class MainTaskListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MainTask.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainTaskSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('maintask/', MainTaskListCreateView.as_view(), name='maintask-list'),
    path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

**test_views.py:**

```
USER = get_user_model()

class MainTaskTest(APITestCase):
    url_verification = reverse('token_obtain_pair')
    url_maintasks = reverse('maintask-list')

    def setUp(self):
        self.email = 'johndoe@email.com'
        self.password = 'johndoepassword'
        self.data = {
            'email': self.email,
            'password': self.password
        }
        USER.objects.create_user(email=self.email, password=self.password)

    def test_auth_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.url_verification, self.data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertTrue('access' in response.data)
        self.assertTrue('refresh' in response.data)

    def test_get_obj(self):
        response_verification = self.client.post(self.url_verification, self.data, format='json')
        token = response_verification.data['access']
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"JWT {token}")
    
        response = self.client.get(self.url_maintasks, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertNotEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        self.assertNotEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

**Problem:**

When running the test above, I get an error *403*, the permission is denied. But when adding the *permission_classes* to my view like so...

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

...everything works fine and the test passes. But - additionally - when adding another permission...

```
permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated,)
```

...the error 403 appears again. Did anybody else had this problem as well, am I missing something or what is going on? Same goes for changing the *default-settings* to only *IsAuthenticated*!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I overlooked what's called [Composed Permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/). But to be fair, it's actually documented inside the Announcement of version 3.9.
Anyway...all I had to do was ...

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser | IsAuthenticated]
```